# SSIS. How to save data from a table having column with type nvarchar(max) to raw file destination

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to transfer a table between two `sql` servers using `ssis.` `OLEDB Source` to get data from `SQL Table` and `destination` is raw file save data.

Problem is that some columns have type `nvarchar(max)` and I suggest it's not suitable for raw file destination.

Converting data type into `dt_wstr` doesn't help because `dt_wstr` has max length of `4000` and it's not enough for my data.
How can I save table to file?

Comment: please let me know is your purpose is resolved or not?

Comment: If you are transferring data between SQL Servers you can connect directly

Comment: I cannot connect directly, only through file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Open `OLE DB Source` in `Advance Editor` and change the `data type` to `DT_TEXT` from `DT_WSTR` or you can use Data Conversion Task to change the data type from `DT_WSTR` to `DT_TEXT` between `OLE DB Source` and `Destination`.

For example ,I have attached snapshot for your refrence.

[image]

Now Changed it for the same column `Country` and save the `Advance Editor`.

[image]

Comment: No, It doesn't work for me. As I wrote, [DT_WSTR] has max length of 4000 characters and my data is longer than that. If I don't use any type conversion, output type will be [DT_NTEXT] which is not suitable for raw file destination.